# What would happen to our universe if an object of infinite mass suddenly appeared?

Tags: gravity, mass, universe

The scenario is this: randomly, an object of infinite mass but of a limited size appears in our universe. What would happen to the rest of the universe? My intuition is that everything else in the universe would start to accelerate towards it, but because the objects mass is infinite wouldn't the acceleration also be infinite? In this case wouldn't every object in the universe start to travel at light speed, thus also becoming infinitely massive?

Answer (score 3):

The theory we would have to use in order to answer this question is general relativity. General relativity says that mass is conserved. (The fully correct technical statement is slightly more complicated.) So our theories can't answer this question, since it requires an assumption that is inconsistent with our theories.

Answer (score 1):

The sudden appearance of such an object would convert the entire universe, instantly, into a black hole.

The only "hair" on this is whether you wish to instantly make the object appear at one point and let its presence become known at light speed or if you wish to convert the whole universe to its presence all at once in all frames.

I should add that there is nothing in Ben's answer that I disagree with.